# Should HTTPRequest return the same as curl in this case

Tags: http-functions

The following shell script is used to access an IoT device that returns a JSON string, the content of which is not important for this question.

```
#!/bin/sh
secret= <not_telling>
id="e00fce688e6bcd0bad0763e7"
curl -k "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/$id/peek" -d access_token=$<not_telling> -d args=5
```

I would like to reproduce this functionality in Mathematica

```
(* id and secret have been defined *)
req = HTTPRequest[
  "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/" <> id <> "/peek",
  <|"Method" -> "POST", 
   "Query" -> {"args" -> "5", "access_token" -> secret}|>]
URLExecute@req
```

This code does successfully POST; however it behaves as if the "-d args=5" portion of the query is missing or ignored.  I'm likely missing something trivial, but cannot place my finger on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *curl* request is passing the arguments as a form body, but the *Mathematica* expression is passing query arguments in the URL.  Try changing the request property `"Query"` to `"Body"` to match the *curl* request:

```
req = HTTPRequest[
  "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/" <> id <> "/peek",
  <|"Method" -> "POST", 
    "Body" -> {"args" -> "5", "access_token" -> secret}|>]
URLExecute@req
```

Comment: Very nice catch.  While you were solving my problem, I was reproducing the same (incorrect) behavior in python.